# How can i access instance variables in closure（inner function） for this style:this['varName']?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, closures

How can I access instance variables in closure（inner function） for this style: `this['varName']`?

```
public class Test extends Sprite
{
    private var a0:String = 'a0';
    private var a1:String = 'a1';
    private var a2:String = 'a2';

    public function Test()
    {
        var testFun:Function = function(evt:Event):void
        {
            for(var i:uint = 0; i < 3; i += 1)
            {
                trace(this['a'+i]);//how to access instance variables?
            }
        };
        this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, testFun);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Square brackets can be used to access properties of an `Object` (everything) exactly as you've done above:

```
object[propertyName]
```

Or set properties, assuming that your class is either `dynamic` or already has the property you're trying to set:

```
object[propertyName] = 10;
```

With an Object, you're actually able to use a `for(String in Object)` loop to output all of the properties you want:

```
var object:Object = {
    test: "string",
    another: 5
};

for(var i:String in object)
{
    trace(i + ": " + object[i]);
}
```

As for your current code, restructure it:

```
public class Test extends Sprite
{
    private var a0:String = 'a0';
    private var a1:String = 'a1';
    private var a2:String = 'a2';

    public function Test()
    {
        testFun();
    }

    public function testFun():void
    {
        for(var i:uint = 0; i < 3; i += 1)
        {
            trace(this['a'+i]);
        }
    }
}
```

---

If you *must* retain your inner function, parse a reference to your current instance of `Test` into it:

```
var testFun:Function = function(subject:Test):void
{
    for(var i:uint = 0; i < 3; i += 1)
    {
        trace(subject['a'+i]);//how to access instance variables?
    }
};
```

And then:

```
testFun(this);
```

Comment: Many thanks.I understand this.But i want access properties in inner function. and now `this` is not the class instance.

Comment: Your inner function is *extremely* bad practice but I'll edit my answer to cater for it..

Comment: Thanks a lot.There have many way for this code works.this code only my question example.My inner function already had a parameter,it is an event callback function.see the question.

Comment: Ok in that case use `Test(evt.target)['a'+i];`

Comment: @Marty: I do trace `this` within the function and the inner function. I got 2 diff output [object MainTimeline]` and `[object global]`. Why?

Comment: I know the inner function's scope chain can access properties.but use `this` it's not works. `eval('')` can do it.but no longer in actionscript 3.`internal::['name']` can access outer function's variables,not instance variables. how can i do this?

Comment: `Test(evt.target)['a'+i]` OK.any other way? The question is not how to find the Test for parameter. Because in my project is an static variables in other file addEventListener,is an Event Control Class,not this.I think it's an inner function,must hava some way to access properties. beacuse `trace(a1);` in testFun, it's ok.

Comment: This question has exceeded my patience through information being added everytime I update my answer.